# Translate SQL statement with SUM() in Entity

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I try to translate this SQL code :

```
SELECT w.Id, w.LastName, w.FirstName, SUM(d.Price*dt.Number) AS somme
FROM  Waiter w
INNER JOIN  Client c on w.Id = c.WaiterId
INNER JOIN  DisheOnTable dt on c.Id = dt.ClientId
INNER JOIN  Dishe d on dt.DisheId = d.Id
GROUP BY w.Id, w.LastName, w.FirstName
ORDER BY somme DESC;
```

in entity framework.

I tried something like this

```
var query2 = (from w in db.Waiter
              join c in db.Client on w.Id equals c.WaiterId
              join dt in db.DisheOnTable on c.Id equals dt.ClientId
              join d in db.Dishe on dt.DisheId equals d.Id
              group w by new { w.Id, w.LastName, w.FirstName } into g
              //orderby g.Select() descending
              select new
              {
                  id = g.Key.Id,
                  lastname = g.Key.LastName,
                  firstname = g.Key.FirstName,
                  total = g.Sum(q => q.)
              });
```

but my sum doesn't work (after multiple research and try) and i don't know how to multiply my variables.

PS : The SQL statement works well, i tried it.

Thank you for helping guys ! :)

Comment: i've an error "d doesn't exist in this context" :/

Comment: what about to split in several code lines:  `var q1 = ... quals dt.ClientId join d in db.Dishe on dt.DisheId equals d.Id select new { w.Id, w.LastName, w.FirstName, d.Price, dt.Number } ; ` and then `var query2 =  from q in q1 group by new  { q.Id, q.LastName, q.FirstName } into g select new ... total = g.Sum( q =>  q.Price * q.Number) } ; `  ( remember than q1 is not executed until you start to consume `query2` )

Comment: summarizing ... first query with all needed fields, second query aggregating fields. ( remember, in fact, first query is never executed, it is only a declaration that will be use in second one )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group on both `dish` and `DishOnTable` alias as `Price` is in `Dish` and `Number` is in `DishOnTable`:

```
group new{ d,dt} by new {w.Id, w.LastName, w.FirstName} into g
```

and now sum the columns which you want from it

```
 select new { 
             id = g.Key.Id, 
             lastname = g.Key.LastName, 
             firstname = g.Key.FirstName, 
             total = g.Sum(q => q.d.Price * q.dt.Number)
            }).OrderBy(x=>x.total)
```

Comment: it works for price, do you know how i can group on DisheOnTable too ? i need to have access on Number

Comment: Yes @danihp it is anonymous object actually we need to use it to group on multiple tables

Comment: It works ! Thank you ! A last question, how can i order by my Sum ? orderby g.Sum() don't work.

Comment: Thank you so much! You got it ! What a pro :P !

Comment: I know, I can't vote it for twice .... this is the answer of the day ;) I will publish it on twitter ...